# Require multiple files

Tags: php, include, require

I am building a PHP application that uses a select menu to build email templates.  The templates are broken into reusable parts (each is a separate html file).  Is there an easy way to require multiple files with one expression?  (my PHP is really rusty...)

Essentially I want to do something like:

```
function require_multi() {
    require_once($File1);
    require_once($File2);
    require_once($File3);
    require_once($File4);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you could turn it into a function:

```
function require_multi($files) {
    $files = func_get_args();
    foreach($files as $file)
        require_once $file;
}
```

Use like this:

```
require_multi("one.php", "two.php", ..);
```

However, if you're including classes, a better solution would be to use [autoloading](https://www.php.net/autoload).

Answer (score 2):

Because you want to require or include multiple files, you could use this recursive
algorithm to include files in a specified folder.  The folder is the root that starts
the iterator.  Because the algorithm is recursive, it will automatically traverse all
subsequent folders and include those files as well.

```
public function include_all_files($root) {
    $d = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root);
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($d) as $file => $f) {
        $ext = pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($ext == 'php' || $ext == 'inc')
            include_once $file; // or require, require_once, include_once()
    }
}

include_all_files('./lib');
```

Comment: This solution is only good if he wants to load classes. Thus, those utilities functions that he reuses may not be in classes. So, it's not a good answer I guess for it's problem. Still, it's an interesting one for loading classes automatically.

Comment: `$d = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($fullPath, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);` Use this for skipping dots