# Is is possible to get file output buffer without including the file?

Tags: php, buffer, output-buffering

Is it possible to get file output buffer string to execute the file in background instead of including it?

Right now this is the only way which I have seen. See code below;

```
ob_start();
include($file);
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

But I have list of files which I don't want to include. I just want to execute the file in background process for getting output buffer string.

Can anyone please help me on it?

Thanks
Smac

Comment: Maybe just fetch the contents ? [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

Comment: It does not execute the php tags. I need a string with php executed tags. I also have checked for eval() already. It does not work perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is php you need to use include.For multiple files you can use function like this I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638060/require-multiple-files)

```
function include_multi($files) {
    $files = func_get_args();
    foreach($files as $file)
        include($file);
}
```

And call it with

```
include_multi("one.php", "two.php", ..);
```

Also If you want plain file contents(No need to execute file) you can use 
[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)  or [readfile](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: I have html source file with php tags. If I include file then html will be render in web browser which I don't want. I just want to get buffer string of each file. So can you please advice me the best solution for this?

Comment: You can use file_get_contents for that.

Comment: file_get_contents() only returns the string. Does not execute the php tags.

Comment: For that you have to do some string manipulation like getting contents between <?php and ?> and then use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to execute that php code.

Comment: I also have already tried eval and done in this way. I found the another approach. I'm testing it now. I think I have fixed it. I will answer shortly. But thanks for your kind help. Appreciated!.