# PHP use array to require php files

Tags: php, require

I have saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638060/require-multiple-files)  about require multiple php files,
I want to do it use class,like this

```
class Core
{
    function loadClass($files)
    {
        $this->files = func_get_args();
        foreach($files as $file) {
            require dirname(__FILE__)."/source/class/$file";
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use

```
$load = new Core;
$load->loadClass('class_template.php');
```

it doesn't work, can anyone help me to find the error ?

Comment: because you are reading `$files` as array and sending it as a string. just add one new line under loadClass file. `if(!is_array($files)){ $files = array($files)}` or when you are calling your files pass it in array like. `$load->loadClass(['class_template.php'])`

Comment: I would recommend looking into `PSR0` or `PSR4` auto loading of classes.

Comment: @AshishPatel thanks,now I know how different array between class and pure function

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I know that,but I just want to require 5 or 6 class files,so I decide make an require function file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `$this->files` to `foreach`. `$files` is a local variable and a string. `$this->files` is a instance variable and an array.

```
class Core {
    function loadClass() { // there is no need for `$files` here
        $this->files = func_get_args();
        foreach($this->files as $file) { // $this->files not $files
            require dirname(__FILE__)."/source/class/$file";
        }
    }
}

$load = new Core;
$load->loadClass('class_template.php');
```

Comment: I will try it,wait for a moment